# Using TypeORM CLI with Yarn Berry and TS Path Aliases

Tags: typeorm, ts-node, yarn-v2

How can you pass the `tsconfig-paths/register` module to `ts-node` when using `typeorm-ts-node-commonjs`?

Most examples show an interface like: `ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm.cli.js`

[The docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-cli.md#if-entities-files-are-in-typescript) vaguely say "If you want to load more modules like module-alias you can add more `--require my-module-supporting-register`" but do not provide a usage example in conjunction with using the prebuilt type orm command `typeorm-ts-node-commonjs`.

I have tried something like `yarn typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -r tsconfig-paths/register` but that doesn't work as "-r" is not a arg of `typeorm-ts-node-commonjs`. I have also tried something like `ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register typeorm-ts-node-commonjs` but then `typeorm-ts-node-commonjs` is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have this solved by doing the following:

```
NODE_OPTIONS='-r ./.pnp.cjs -r tsconfig-paths/register' typeorm-ts-node-commonjs
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I added this config, in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "require": [
      "tsconfig-paths/register"
    ]
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
         ...
     }
}
```